# Write a Python program that repeatedly asks the user to input coin values until the total amount matches a target value

Tags: python

However, I realized that I don't actually know how to do this myself without examining every possible combination of coins. There has to be a better way of solving this problem, but I don't know what the generic name for this type of algorithm would be called, and I can't figure out a way to simplify it beyond looking at every solution.

I was wondering if anybody could point me in the right direction, or offer up an algorithm that's more efficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
MaxAmount = 100
TotalAmount = 0

while TotalAmount < MaxAmount:
    #Here if you want it to be more precise on decimals change int(raw_input("Amount: ")) to float(raw_input("Amount: "))
    EnteredAmount = float(raw_input("Amount: "))
    if EnteredAmount > MaxAmount:
        print "You can not go over 100"
    elif TotalAmount > MaxAmount:
        #You can go two ways here either just set TotalAmount to MaxAmount or just cancel the input
        print "You can not go over 100"
    elif EnteredAmount <= MaxAmount:
        TotalAmount = TotalAmount + EnteredAmount
        print TotalAmount
print "You have reached the total amount of ", MaxAmount
```

Comment: Can you look another question. this is link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26223346/write-a-python-program-that-repeatedly-asks-the-user-to-input-coin-values-until/26223797#26223797

Answer (score 0):

Could use a loop into an if - elif - else statements
e.g. populate a variable with your amount, then using this for the loop condition keep asking to take away coin amounts until you reach 0