# Write a Python program that repeatedly asks the user to input coin values until the total amount matches a target value

Tags: python, python-3.x

Write a Python program that repeatedly asks the user to input coin values until 
the total amount matches a target value. The target value is a randomly 
generated integer between 1 and 99 (inclusive).

For example, for a target value of 31, coin values entered by the user could 
be 25, 5, and 1 because 31 = 25 + 5 + 1.

In order to generate a random number in Python for the target value, you have to 
write the following statement at the start of your program:

```
import random
```

You can then write the following statement in your program to generate a random 
number:

```
rand = random.randint(1, 99)
```

The above statement will generate a random number between 1 and 99 (both 
end points are inclusive). This random number will be stored in the variable rand 
(as per the above statement). You may use a different variable name if you want. 
The random value stored in the variable named rand is the target coin value 
that the user has to enter coins for.

Sample Run of the Program

On the following page is a complete sample run of the program. This is an 
example of how the program will behave; in the following same, 59, 70 and 76 
are randomly generated numbers.

Example:
The purpose of this exercise is to enter a number of coin values 
that add up to a displayed target value.

Enter coins values as 1-penny, 5-nickel, 10-dime, and 25-quarter. 
Hit return after the last entered coin value.

---

```
Enter coins that add up to 59 cents, one per line. 
Enter first coin: 
Enter first coin: 3 
Invalid entry 
Enter first coin: 25 
Enter next coin: 5 
Enter next coin: 25 
Enter next coin: 2 
Invalid entry 
Enter next coin: 1 
Enter next coin: 1 
Enter next coin: 1 
Enter next coin: 1 
Enter next coin: 
Correct! 
Try again (y/n)?: y 
Enter coins that add up to 70 cents, one per line. 
Enter first coin: 2 
Invalid entry 
Enter first coin: 25 
Enter next coin: 25 
Enter next coin: 10 
Enter next coin: 5 
Enter next coin: 1 
Enter next coin: 25 
Sorry - total amount exceeds 70 cents. 
Try again (y/n)?: y 
Enter coins that add up to 76 cents, one per line. 
Enter first coin: 25 
Enter next coin: 25 
Enter next coin: 1 
Enter next coin: 25 
Enter next coin: 
Correct! 
Try again (y/n)?: n 
Thanks for playing ... goodbye
```

This is the code that I have so far:

```
import random

def chkcoin(acoin):
    basecoin = ["1"," 5", "10", "25"]
    flag = False
    for bc in basecoin:
        if acoin == int(bc):
            return True
        else:
            flag = True
    if flag:
        print('Invalid entry')
        return False

def tryAgain():
    comd = input('Try again (y/n)?: ')
    if comd == 'y':
        return True
    elif comd == 'n':
        print ('Thanks for playing ... goodbye')
        return False
    else:
        print ('Command error! Please enter y or n.')
        print ('Thanks for playing ... goodbye')
        return False
```

import random

```
def chkcoin(acoin): basecoin = ["1"," 5", "10", "25"] flag = False for bc in basecoin: if acoin == int(bc): return True else: flag = True if flag: print('Invalid entry') return False def tryAgain(): comd = input('Try again (y/n)?: ') if comd == 'y': return True elif comd == 'n': print ('Thanks for playing ... goodbye') return False else: print ('Command error! Please enter y or n.') print ('Thanks for playing ... goodbye') return False
```

Can someone help me? i have 2question need to solve.

1. when i need enter number. if i enter spacebar. this program will crash. i want if i enter spacebar, the result will same like 8 or another. "invalid try"
2. this python will crash after one game. how to solve it? i write this python in python2. suddenly, i find i need write in python3. but i do not know how to change it. ty

Comment: Is here no policy that prevents people from asking others to do their homework?!?

Comment: Or a wrong perseverance badge http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26203695/write-a-python-program-that-repeatedly-asks-the-user-to-input-coin-values-until

Comment: This forum isn't here to get other people to do your homework for you.  You need to show that you've actually put some effort into solving it yourself, not just post the entire question here verbatim.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to look at a [while](https://wiki.python.org/moin/WhileLoop) loop

eg:

```
# Set the target value
target = 50
# Initialize the running total to 0
total = 0
run the indented code while target != total
while total != target:
    # ask the user for a number
    choice = input("Number? ")
    # add choice to total
    total += choice
```

The above will keep running the `while` block while `total != 50` evaluates to `True`.

Comment: @mmmmmm111 Can you tell me which part is confusing so I can explain?

Comment: i write a py work on python2. but i find i need use python3 to write. and now i have no idea how to change them..

Answer (score 0):

```
import random
def amountGame():
   coin=[25,5,1]
   target=random.randint(1,99)
   print(f'Your Amount is {target}')
   total=0
   while target!=total:
       x=int(input('Enter pic of amount :'))
       if x in coin and (target-total)>=x:
           total+=x
       else:
           print('Envalid Entry')
   print('You Solve problam')


opt=''
while opt!='N':
    amountGame()
    opt=input('Do you want to continue press Y else N :).upper()
```

Comment: Hi, please provide some explanation, rather than just code. See the ["How do I write a good answer?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) page.